# How to call function with a function parameter that has a parameterized return type

Tags: dart

My understanding of dart is that `Function<T>()` is a type representing a function who's return type is T. So if I want to provide such a function as a callback:

```
T wrapper<T>(Function<T>() f){
  return f();
}
```

... which compiles.

But when calling the wrapper and providing a function with some return type, I get:

```
int myF()=>123;

callWrapper(){
  int i = wrapper(myF);  <<< error with myF
}
```

```
error: The argument type 'int Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function<T>()'. (argument_type_not_assignable at ....
```

I don't get it. Why did the type checker think that `int Function()` doesn't match `Function<T>()`?

Also failing in the same way:

```
T wrapper<T>(T Function() f){    ///<<<<
  return f();
}

int myF()=>123;

callWrapper(){
  int i = wrapper(myF);
}
```

Comment: Here the code runs fine without any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the parameter `Function<T>() f` is not saying that "`f` a `Function` that takes no arguments and returns a `T`", it is actually saying "`f` is a `Function<T>` that takes no arguments and returns `dynamic`".

There are two ways you can make this work:

1.

```dart
T wrapper<T>(T Function() f) { ... }
```

2.

```dart
T wrapper<T>(T f()) { ... }
```

The class `Function` from `dart:core` doesn't have any type variables. I think the analyzer should be warning you about doing `Function<T>()` but it isn't.